# How to tell if AVAsset was recording using the front camera?

Tags: ios, camera, avasset

When selecting a video using UIImagePickerController and requestAVAssetForVideo, I get an AVAsset. I'm transforming this asset based on the orientation. I'd also like to flip the asset if it was taken with the front camera.

I compared the preferredTransform of an asset taken with the back camera and an asset taken with the front camera. The only difference is the width and height:

```
CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: -1.0, tx: 1280.0, ty: 720.0)
CGAffineTransform(a: -1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: -1.0, tx: 1920.0, ty: 1080.0)
```

How can I determine if an AVAsset track was taken with the front camera?

Comment: Is there anything about this in the metadata?

Comment: @matt Just had a look and didn't see anything. No results when searching either. Good thinking though. Does anything know if it's in there?